# Vercel NestJS deployment failing with type issues

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, vercel, tsconfig

#### Background:

I am working on a leisure project that connects with different Google services to ease my daily personal routine. The `NodeJS` code, available on `main` branch, works fine i.e Vercel deployment is success but now I am migrating it to `NestJS` so I can scale the app.

Repo: [Github repo](https://github.com/kamlekar/gcal-slack)

#### Issue

NestJS deployment on Vercel is throwing type issues that can be seen in Vercel logs & deployment status -> building. It works fine locally but not on Vercel deployment.

My assumption is the issue to be in `tsconfig` file. Here is the code in it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "target": "ES6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
  }
}
```

For more details, please check this [github issue link](https://github.com/kamlekar/gcal-slack/issues/1)

### Update:

I was able to fix the type issues to a good extent. Strangely, the type issues were only visible in Vercel deployment logs. I believe there is only one issue now i.e. the Vercel is unable to pickup the `*.njk` files in deployment.

Here is the work in progress [Github PR](https://github.com/kamlekar/gcal-slack/pull/2)

### Update2:

Raised a issue on Vercel for nunjucks template not found

[issue](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2274)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were type issues and strangely only visible on Vercel deployment logs. I was unable to reproduce them locally. Anyway, I will list out the main fixes here. All fixes are available in this [PR](https://github.com/kamlekar/gcal-slack/pull/2).

### tsconfig fix

- `"esModuleInterop": true` in `CompilerOptions`.

Strangely, all solutions on SO were suggesting to keep this as `false`.

### Allowing `*.njk` nunjucks templates in server & Vercel deployment

Vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "**/*.njk",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    }
  ],
  ...
  ...
}
```

nest-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": ["**/*.njk"]
  }
}
```

### Fetching `Request` and `Response` types from `express-serve-static-core` instead of `express` ‍♂️

```
import type { Request, Response } from 'express-serve-static-core';
```

instead of

```
import type { Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

- exception in handler function of `/`
- type checking error

it seems that you should fix `fileUpload` is not a function issue to prevent that `500`;

The second point is a general approach regarding vercel deployments for build error; since build errors (including typechecking errors) are specific to each project:

#### solution

run `build` command locally and fix all the issues as happen one by one; if build command runs with no error in your machine it wouldnt have issues on vercel as well;

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `pnpm run build` is passing locally. I think the issue is with typescript or tsconfig.json.

Comment: @Mr_Green there is no tsconfig file in the repo provided in question

Comment: it should be there for `nestjs-try` git branch. I am currently working on a solution.